# Using jQuery efects backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a question about the using the jQuery effects in backbone.
Basically what I want to achieve:
I have a app when after clicking show more question button app load more tasks I want to delay this process for about one sec and add throbber to this while its loading. Second effect which I want to achieve is to add fadeIn() effect after the loading is done and the more tasks are appearing.
The code:

```
$(function() {
var Tasks = Backbone.Model.extend();
var TasksList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Tasks,
    url: 'json/data.json',

}); 


var TasksView = Backbone.View.extend({

el: '#content',
con: 3,
events: {
    'click #load-more': 'onClickMore',
    'click .avatar': 'avatarClick',
    'click .answer > a': 'answerClick',
    'click .other-questions': 'questionsClick'
},

template: _.template($('#taskTemplate').html()),

initialize: function () {
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.render);


},
renderTask: function (task) {
    var html;

    html = this.template(task.toJSON());

    this.$el.append(html);
},


render: function () {
    var tasks = this.collection.first(this.con);

    _.each(tasks, this.renderTask, this);

    this.count = tasks.length;
},
onClickMore: function (event) {
    var tasks = this.collection.models.slice(this.count, this.count + this.con);

    event.preventDefault();

    if (tasks.length) {
        _.each(tasks, this.renderTask, this);

        this.count += tasks.length;
    } else {
        alert('Limit of tasks for you is reached');
    }
},
avatarClick: function (event) {
    alert("You clicked avatar!");
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
},
answerClick: function (event) {
    alert("You clicked answer button!");
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
},
questionsClick: function (event) {
    alert("You clicked whole task!");
    event.preventDefault();
}

});

var tasks = new TasksList(),   
tasksView = new TasksView({ collection: tasks });
tasks.fetch({ reset:true });

});
```

Comment: It would help if you had a working example on jsfiddle

Comment: Here is a whole code http://jsfiddle.net/23x5xhnu/ dont know how to pass data for json so the are here:
http://www.ulesiow.pl/data.json